# Problems with HTML and Javascript dynamic table

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, dom-events

I am facing problems in:

1. the function `saveRow` does not save the row. I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property name of undefined at at saveRow at HTMLInputElement.onclick.
> 2) the `deleteRow` does not work. I get a similar error:
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null.
> 3) in the `editRow`, I fields to become editable, but with the default values as what was saved before. For example, the list is always A, B, C which is not what I want. I want the initial value of the list to be what was selected previously.

There should be something wrong I am doing. Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <table align='center' cellspacing=2 cellpadding=5 id="data_table" border=1>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Level</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="table-rows">
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" id="name-text"></td>
          <td>
            <select name="levels-list" id="levels-list">
    <option value="A" id="option-1">A</option>
    <option value="B" id="option-2">B</option>
    <option value="C" id="option-3">C</option>
    </select>
          </td>
          <td><input type="button" class="add" value="Add Row" id="add-button"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
<script src="get-text.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The script:

```
var myArray = [{
  "name": "aaa",
  "level": "A"
}, {
  "name": "bbb",
  "level": "B"
}, {
  "name": "ccc",
  "level": "C"
}];


display();

function display() {
  var length = myArray.length;
  var htmlText = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    htmlText +=
      "<tr id='row" + i + "'>\
                <td>" + myArray[i].name + "</td>\
                <td>" + myArray[i].level + "</td>\
                <td>\
                    <input type='button' id='edit_button" + i + "' value='Edit' class='edit' onclick='editRow("+i+")'> \
                    <input type='button' id='save_button" + i + "' value='Save' class='save' onclick='save_row(" + i + ")'> \
                    <input type='button' value='Delete' class='delete' onclick='delete_row(" + i + ")'>\
                </td>\
            </tr>";
  }//end loop
  htmlText+=
  "<tr>\
    <td><input type='text' id='name-text'></td>\
    <td>\
      <select name='levels-list' id='levels-list'>\
        <option value='A' id='option-1'>A</option>\
        <option value='B' id='option-2'>B</option>\
        <option value='C' id='option-3'>C</option>\
        </select>\
    </td>\
    <td><input type='button' class='add' value='Add Row' id='add-button' ></td>\
  </tr>";

  document.getElementById("table-rows").innerHTML = htmlText;
}//end display

var addButton=document.getElementById("add-button");
addButton.addEventListener('click', addRow, false);

function addRow(){
  event.preventDefault();
  var newData= document.getElementById("name-text").value;
  var newLevel = document.getElementById("levels-list").value;

  var table = document.getElementById("data_table");
  var tableLength = (table.rows.length)-1;
//  console.log(tableLength);
  var row = table.insertRow(tableLength).innerHTML=
   "<tr id= 'row"+tableLength+"'>\
        <td id='name-text"+tableLength+"'>"+newData+"</td>\
        <td id='levels-list"+tableLength+"'>"+newLevel+"</td>\
        <td><input type='button' id='edit-button"+tableLength+"' value='Edit' class='edit' onclick='editRow("+tableLength+")'> \
            <input type='button' id='save-button"+tableLength+"' value='Save' class='save' onclick='saveRow("+tableLength+")'> \
            <input type='button' id= 'delete-button"+tableLength+"' value='Delete' class='delete' onclick='deleteRow("+tableLength+")'>\
        </td>\
   </tr>";

  document.getElementById("name-text").value="";
}//end addRow

function editRow(no)
{
  document.getElementById("edit-button"+no).disabled=true;
   //document.getElementById("save-button"+no).style.display="block";

   var name=document.getElementById("name-text"+no);
   var level=document.getElementById("levels-list"+no);

   var nameData=name.innerHTML;
   var levelData=level.innerHTML;

   name.innerHTML="<input type='text' id='name_text"+no+"' value='"+nameData+"'>";
   level.innerHTML='<select id="levels-list'+no+'">\
                      <option value="A" id="option-1">A</option>\
                      <option value="B" id="option-2">B</option>\
                      <option value="C" id="option-3">C</option>\
                      </select>' ;

  document.getElementById("levels-list"+no).value = levelData;
}

function deleteRow(no) {
  myArray.splice(no, 1);
  document.getElementById("row"+no).innerHTML="";
  //display();
} //end deleteRow

function saveRow(no)
{
  myArray[no].name = document.getElementById("name-text"+no).value;
  myArray[no].level = document.getElementById("levels-list"+no).value;

  document.getElementById("row"+no).innerHTML =
  "<tr id= 'row"+no+"'>\
    <td id='name-text"+no+"'>"+myArray[no].name+"</td>\
    <td id='levels-list"+no+"'>"+myArray[no].level+"</td>\
    <td><input type='button' id='edit-button"+no+"' value='Edit' class='edit' onclick='editRow("+no+")'> \
        <input type='button' value='Delete' class='delete' onclick='deleteRow("+no+")'>\
    </td>\
   </tr>";
}//end saveRow
```

Answer (score 0):

I refactored a bit your code and created a new jsfiddle. You can refactor it more and more, and if possible to insert jQuery in your project, you will simply it a lot more.

So few notes:

1) Keep you model up to date with your UI changes. In the before sample you were manipulating HTML but you were not updating the array model

2) Try to keep your common code in functions, in order to avoid repetitions. 
For example I moved the logic for creating row inside a function, and just calling that function every time that you need to create a new row (for displaying at the beginning and when clicking add row)

3) When you call your functions in the row, pass also the current HTML element. You can pass it in order to know which current HTML element has been clicked, so that you can easily manipulate that row.

4) Use two tbodies. One for the data and another one for the actions. It makes easier to distinct data from actions, avoiding to repeat every time also that row for actions

And few other things that you can check alone with the code.

You have to manage just the logic of disabling the buttons in the right operations, in order to avoid for example to click edit again when editing, but it would be a good exercise to do it yourself :)

Here the sample:

```js
var myArray = [{
  "name": "aaa",
  "level": "A"
}, {
  "name": "bbb",
  "level": "B"
}, {
  "name": "ccc",
  "level": "C"
}];

function createDataRow(el, ind) {
  var row = document.createElement('tr');
  row.id = 'row-' + ind;
  var cell1Content = `
   <div class="name-content">${el.name}</div>
    <input class="name-edit" type="text" id="name-text-${ind}" value="${el.name}" style="display:none;">
  `;
  
  var cell2Content = `
   <div class="level-content">${el.level}</div>
   <select class="level-edit" id="levels-list-${ind}" style="display:none;">
      <option value="A">A</option>\
      <option value="B">B</option>\
      <option value="C">C</option>\
    </select>
  `;
  
  var cell3Content = `
    <input type="button" id='edit_button" + i + "' value="Edit" class="edit" onclick="editRow(this, ${ind})">
    <input type="button" id='save_button" + i + "' value="Save" class="save" onclick="saveRow(this, ${ind})">
    <input type="button" value="Delete" class="delete" onclick="deleteRow(this, ${ind})">
  `;
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  
  cell1.innerHTML = cell1Content;
  cell2.innerHTML = cell2Content;
  cell3.innerHTML = cell3Content;
  
  document.getElementById('table-data').appendChild(row);
}

function displayData() {
  myArray.forEach(function(el, ind) {
   createDataRow(el,ind);
  });
}

function deleteRow(el, ind) {
 el.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.removeChild(el.parentElement.parentElement); 
  myArray.splice(ind, 1);
}

function addRow(){
  event.preventDefault();
  var newEl = {
   "name": document.getElementById("name-text").value,
    "level": document.getElementById("levels-list").value
  };
  myArray.push(newEl);
  createDataRow(newEl, myArray.length - 1);
  document.getElementById("name-text").value = '';
  document.getElementById("levels-list").value = 'A';
}//end addRow

function editRow(el, ind)
{
 var currentRow = el.parentElement.parentElement;
  
  currentRow.cells[0].getElementsByClassName("name-content")[0].style.display = 'none';
  currentRow.cells[0].getElementsByClassName("name-edit")[0].style.display = 'block';
  
  currentRow.cells[1].getElementsByClassName("level-content")[0].style.display = 'none';
  currentRow.cells[1].getElementsByClassName("level-edit")[0].value = myArray[ind].level;
  currentRow.cells[1].getElementsByClassName("level-edit")[0].style.display = 'block';
}
 //end deleteRow

function saveRow(el, ind)
{
 var currentRow = el.parentElement.parentElement;
  
  var nameContent = currentRow.cells[0].getElementsByClassName("name-content")[0];
  var nameEdit = currentRow.cells[0].getElementsByClassName("name-edit")[0];
  nameContent.innerHTML = nameEdit.value;
  nameContent.style.display = 'block';
  nameEdit.style.display = 'none';
  
  var levelContent = currentRow.cells[1].getElementsByClassName("level-content")[0];
  var levelEdit = currentRow.cells[1].getElementsByClassName("level-edit")[0];
  levelContent.innerHTML = levelEdit.value;
  levelContent.style.display = 'block';
  levelEdit.style.display = 'none';
  
  myArray[ind].name = nameEdit.value;
  myArray[ind].level = levelEdit.value;
}//end saveRow

var addButton=document.getElementById("add-button");
addButton.addEventListener('click', addRow, false);
displayData();
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <table align='center' cellspacing=2 cellpadding=5 id="data_table" border=1>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Level</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="table-data">
      </tbody>
      <tbody id="table-rows">
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" id="name-text"></td>
          <td>
            <select name="levels-list" id="levels-list">
              <option value="A" id="option-1">A</option>
              <option value="B" id="option-2">B</option>
              <option value="C" id="option-3">C</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td><input type="button" class="add" value="Add Row" id="add-button"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

And here the jsfiddle (this time saved :D ):

https://jsfiddle.net/u0865zaa/8/

I hope it helps. For any queries let me know.

Comment: Thanks. But nothing from what you said really works. The modify you posted is not different from what I posted and does not fix the problem. The code link you give does not run.

Comment: Ok. The edit worked now. But your code in the link is not. None of the buttons (save, edit, delete) is performing the function.

Comment: I didnt save the last version on jsfiddle updating the URL -.-

Comment: Trying to recreate the right version. Delete should work also in the  link I gave you

Comment: Ok I refactored a bit the example and recreated the jsfiddle, updating the answer

Comment: can you read me here? if we go on sending messages, maybe another two, in a while will appear the link to open a chat

Comment: what is the issue? if I run it I can correctly add rows to the tablet

Comment: btw if you want we can switch to chat too

Comment: When I click add, I get: `"{
  "message": "ReferenceError: event is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 96,
  "colno": 3
}"`

Comment: but do you mean in my example or when you copied the code in your file?

Comment: Your example does not allow adding.

Comment: Sure I did, it works to me. Which browser are you using?