# Can't edit this HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I want to be able to edit a row in HTML table. I am trying this code but after running, when I click `edit` button, I get this error: `Cannot set property innerHTML of null`. Can't figure out why.

HTML:

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

</head>

<body id="body">

    <div id="wrapper">
        <table align='center' cellspacing=1 cellpadding=1 id="mytable" border=1>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>


            </thead>
            <tbody id="tbody">
              <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="inputname"></td>

                <td>
                    <select name="levels-list" id="inputlevel">
                    <option value="High" id="option-1">High</option>
                    <option value="Mid" id="option-2">Mid</option>
                    <option value="Low" id="option-3">Low</option>
                    </select>
                </td>

                <td><input type="button" class="add" id="add-button" value="Add"></td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
  <!--  <button onclick='display()'> Display</button> -->
    <script src="get-text.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Script:

```
var myArray = [{ "name": "aaa", "level": "A" }, { "name": "bbb", "level": "B" }, { "name": "ccc", "level": "C" }];

var addButton=document.getElementById("add-button");
addButton.addEventListener('click', addRow, false);

 function addRow(){
    event.preventDefault();
    var newData= document.getElementById("inputname").value;
    var newLevel = document.getElementById("inputlevel").value;
    var table = document.getElementById("mytable");
    var tableLength = (table.rows.length)-1;
    var htmltext=
    "<tr id= 'row"+tableLength+"'>\
      <td id='inputname"+tableLength+"'>"+newData+"</td> \
      <td id='inputlevel"+tableLength+"'>"+newLevel+"</td>\
      <td>\
        <input type='button' id='edit-button"+tableLength+"' value='Edit' class='edit' onclick='editRow("+tableLength+")'> \
        <input type='button' id='save-button"+tableLength+"' value='Save' class='save' onclick='saveRow("+tableLength+")'> \
        <input type='button' id= 'delete-button"+tableLength+"' value='Delete' class='delete' onclick='deleteRow("+tableLength+")'>\
      </td>\
     </tr>";

    table.insertRow(tableLength).innerHTML=htmltext;
}//end addRow

function editRow(no)
{
  var htmltext =
  "<tr>\
    <td><input id='inputname"+no+"' type='text' value='"+myArray[no].name+"'></td>\
    <td>\
    <select id='inputlevel"+no+"'>\
      <option value='A' id='option-1'>A</option> \
      <option value='B' id='option-2'>B</option>\
      <option value='C' id='option-3'>C</option>\
    </select>\
    </td>\
    <td><button onclick='saveRow("+no+")'>Save</button><button onclick='deleteRow("+no+")'>Remove</button></td>\
    </tr>";
  document.getElementById("inputlevel"+no).value=myArray[no].level; //to set the saved element as default when edit button is pressed.
  document.getElementById("row"+no).innerHTML = htmltext;
}//end editRow

function saveRow()
{

}

function deleteRow()
{

}
```

Comment: Your `insertRow` function is overriding your `<tr id='rowX'>` part of your code, so when you do the innerHTML, that tag is basically ignored.

Comment: I already answered to your issues in the other answer you opened: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44210939/problems-with-html-and-javascript-dynamic-table/44211463?noredirect=1#comment75440254_44211463

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems with HTML and javascript dynamic table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44210939/problems-with-html-and-javascript-dynamic-table)

Comment: @quirimmo You did whole new re-writing for the code. I will accept that answer because it is correct but I can't expand that code. Can't you please just point the problem in this post based on my code?

Comment: yes can we move the discussion in the other post and close this one? it is actually a repetition of the other one. Does it sound good for you? We can also have a chat about the previous and new code if it works fine for you

Comment: @quirimmo Where to chat?

Comment: @user7945230 reply to me in the other question below the comments

Comment: I want to continue on my code that I posted here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is exactly what @Lixus mentioned.

> Your insertRow function is overriding your  part of your code, so when you do the innerHTML, that tag is basically ignored. – Lixus

**Solution**

replace this line in your add row function
`table.insertRow(tableLength).innerHTML=htmltext;`

with the following

`var row = table.insertRow(tableLength);
row.setAttribute("id", "row"+tableLength);
row.innerHTML=htmltext;`

Also remove the `tr` tags from the `htmltext`

**Explaination**

- what it does is inserts a row at postion (table length)
- then sets your id attribute to rowX where X is table length
- then sets your innerhtml for that row