# How to assign variable ids to tables rows and columns

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

How can I assign ids to the rows, columns if I want to use this method for creating tables. Knowing that the ids are variables, eg. array length.

```
function addRow(tableID, text) {
  // Get a reference to the table
  var tableRef = document.getElementById(tableID);

  // Insert a row in the table
  var newRow = tableRef.insertRow();

  // Insert a cell in the row
  var newCell = newRow.insertCell();

  // Append a text node to the cell
  var newText = document.createTextNode(text);
  newCell.appendChild(newText);
}

// Call addRow(text) with the ID of a table
addRow('TableA', 'Brand new row');
addRow('TableA', 'Another new row');
```

Comment: This is a sample I made following your logic, and adding ids to rows and columns, not really based on any array length, but kind of takes you where you want: https://jsfiddle.net/lixusrarnavo/oycqvzn9/

Comment: I do not think it is what  Iwant. I want to use getElementByid later on. So how will I do that with your code?

Comment: If you're creating the elements, store the elements at creation time. Why bother performing `getElementById` if you can already have refs to elements?

Comment: Based on your comment, this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) – tell us what you plan on doing with the table instead of asking how to assign ids.

Comment: What I need is to create rows with a column that contains a button. I want to attach a listener to the button so that if it is clicked, it performs the function in that row.

Comment: Here is my main purpose. I want to create a table with edit and delete. If clicked, the function is performed.[link]( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44210939/problems-with-html-and-javascript-dynamic-table/44211463?noredirect=1#comment75447720_44211463)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us say you want to add `k` rows. Simple, create the rows in a loop of `k` iteration.

```
var tableRef = document.getElementById(tableID);

//to add k rows
for (x=0; x<k; x++)
{

  // Insert a row in the table
  var newRow = tableRef.insertRow(x);
  newRow.setAttribute("id","row"+x);

  // Insert a cell in the row
  var newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);

  // Insert another cell in the row
  var newCell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);

  //insert HTML text in the cells
  newCell.innerHTML="text1";
  newCell2.innerHTML="text2";
} //end for

}//end function
```